# Custom data loading, sorting, paging in wijgrid

Tags: wijmo, wijgrid

I have a wijgrid that I need to implement custom paging and sorting (read: server side paging and sorting), but I need to load the data using our custom client side library.  It handles various authentication and XSS procedures that our server side code expects.

So looking at the custom paging samples I sort of need to do a combination of the "Dynamic Data" sample, where I can provide my own `loading` function and the "Remote Data" sample.  The problem with the dynamic data, as I see it, is that it expects the `loading` function to end by setting the dataSource.data property with the data.  In my case I can't do that because I will need to wait for an ajax call to complete and then process the data that is returned.

Is this a possibility or am I totally going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below where it shows custom filtering of data : http://wijmo.com/wijgrid-custom-filtering/
It uses the wijdatasource widget to retrieve data from the server. You can use its 'loaded' event to process the returned data.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that sample, this still isn't quite what I need though.  The main problem is I need much finer control over the ajax requests that are sent, so I can't simply supply a URL to the `wijhttpproxy` and let wijmo just "go get it".  After pouring through the code, I think I can just implement my own custom proxy object and pass that to the `wijdatasource`, as long as I implement all the proper functions.